# How to get Moving Average for each day from Yahoo/Google Finance API?

Tags: api, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance, google-finance

I need the value of Simple Moving Average for each day for Historical data? Is there a way?

Or just for last day?

SMA 20-day, SMA 5-day, SMA 50-day

All this stuff via API or .csv output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a quick google search, I could find a page which answered this [here](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) which explains which special parameters to pass to query the API. Check it out and see if it satisfies your needs or not.

You can use YQL to query this data from the API specified in the link. The link to YQL console to test this can be accessed [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A//download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv%3Fs%3DYHOO%2CGOOG%2CAAPL%26f%3Dsl1d1t1c1ohgvm3i%26e%3D.csv%27%20and%20columns%3D%27symbol%2Cprice%2Cdate%2Ctime%2Cchange%2Ccol1%2Chigh%2Clow%2Ccol2%2Ccol3%2Ccol4%27)

Comment: unfortunately the page you linked got taken down :/ I really need to find a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Based on google finance, this link should work [link](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/simple-moving-average-in-google-sheets/)
Just remember to replace "," comma with semi-colon ";"